# How to get a const enum from value in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two string enums that I'm trying to convert, one to the other, via value.
The enum that I'm trying to get is a const string enum. Since it is const I'm failing to get it.

i.e.:

```
const enum MyEnum1 {
     ORANGE = 'orange',
     YELLOW = 'yellow'
}
enum MyEnum2 {
     ORANGE = 'orange',
     BLACK = 'black',
     YELLOW = 'yellow',

}

function getEnumKeyByEnumValue<T extends {[index:string]:string}>(myEnum:T, enumValue:string):keyof T|null {
    let keys = Object.keys(myEnum).filter(x => myEnum[x] == enumValue);
    return keys.length > 0 ? keys[0] : null;
}

function converter(type2: MyEnum2): MyEnum1 {
     const enumKey = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(MyEnum1, type2);
     if (!enumKey) {
          throw new Error('Key does not exist');
     }
    return MyEnum1[enumKey];
}
```

You can see this example in Typescript Playground at [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgWQJ4FEnIIwwDeAUDGWQPIBKAggHIDiWMAvDAOQgBOAhmAOZx2AGlLkYATSwAZaRQDqrDhjgAbVSADu7YgF9iCFOmy4ATETHlq9Jks68BQ0eJgAhaTQDCAaTsAjVR5gAGsRSzIpWQU7FXUtML1iYgAzRDBgKABLcBhBKBwUbzgMVxMUADUeVUQ4AB4AFXgADygEABMIIgBtTLA2uCaALmguXv4AXWGoUYFdAD4ACmQy5EH64XhcSuq4KZn+AEpB4OKQZJh6gB8kdQtxVThYE4xOtgo-ACs4DIA6Z4glisDj9kplVK0uAsmqw5jBlgVkF0muNWGxDMhtjUDgBucJcR6ILhgGD-H4PARQAAWMFhAAYYAB+EnFCBdWkowYwG6qXH6FJpDLZYmgMAANzgXAhCygGAADnBTJzMAjTEdjAiCCQXCLoJtCsUlHkEUUSitMXAFsrcHgNjL5arcS5MucFgBCdEmg53FziKlcLRcuCaGBYLj+yHsE0wNogOCdMAgWADTLQdg48IwfTifFQQnEq0oPBdD3Fca8oA)

For the converter function I'm getting an error in the last line. I've tried the approaches that relate to non const enum and they only work for non const enum. If enum is defined as const it does not work.

How can it be done?

Comment: What is a "non-const enum"? It does not make any sense

Comment: I don't see a `const enum` in your example.  Your code doesn't work for non-`const` enums either.  I'm not even sure what you expect if someone calls `converter(MyEnum2.BLACK)`, which has no analog in `MyEnum1`.  Do you want it to throw an error?  And since `const enum`s are not emitted to JavaScript, there's no `MyEnum1` or `MyEnum2` objects to iterate through, so maybe what you want is impossible.  In any case I urge you to provide a [mcve] and describe exactly what error you are getting and what the expected input/output relationship of `converter()` is supposed to be.

Comment: @Nikita Ivanov, I've fixed the example. It was missing the const word.

Comment: @jcalz, see above comment. added a playground link. If you cannot help then thanks anyway for the effort in assisting. Alternative solutions are also good except ones that remove the const word from the enum as we generate it automatically in my company.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[TypeScript: Get member name of const enum as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49169727/90527)", "[Getting the enum key with the value string (reverse mapping) in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54297376/90527)"

Comment: I still don't understand what you are actually trying to do in the function; if the enum were not `const` it would fail, since you cannot look use one enum value as the key to a different enum (unless values from one happen to be keys of the other, and in your example they are not).  Your [mcve] should presumably something that *would* work if the enum were not `const`; otherwise you are not demonstrating a problem with `const` versus non-`const` so much as a problem with your logic.  You are trying to do *something* with `converter()`.. what is it?  Show valid input/output pairs.

Comment: @outis, both links are ones I provided....

Comment: @jcalz, updated the description. You can remove const word to make it work

Comment: `enum const` is invalid TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to not be possible according to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227546/4884749

This question is in fact the same scenario described in the linked issue in other words.

const enums are fully erased during compilation which means that runtime evaluation is not possible